# JQTouchPhotoGallery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch

i'm trying to load the images for the JQTouchPhotoGallery dynamic in a $.ajax jquery function. 
but the gallery doesn't show the images, only the loading spinner. also the number of images from the result are not displayed correctly at the top bar (1 of 412)...

```
$(function(){
$(".folio").click(function(){
                var portfolio_id = $(this).attr('id');
                $.ajax({
                async:false,
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "portfolio.php",
                   data: "portfolio_id="+portfolio_id+"",
                   success: function(data){
                     //alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
                     jQT.generateGallery("portfolio-slides-"+portfolio_id,data);
                   }
                 });

});

});
```

the result from the php is:

```
[
{src:"../img/upload/portfolio/portfolio-2_Hochhauser1.jpg"},
{src:"../img/upload/portfolio/portfolio-2_Hochhauser2.jpg"}
]
```

means, the main gallery code script should look like this:

```
jQT.generateGallery("portfolio-slides2",[
{src:"../img/upload/portfolio/portfolio-1_LOOSHAUS_1.jpg"},
{src:"../img/upload/portfolio/portfolio-1_LOOSHAUS_2.jpg"}
]);
```

am i completely wrong with my javascript code?? if i alert the data, all seems to be working. or are there some restrictions which i didn't consider...

any help would be really appreciated, thank you in advance!

greetings, bernhard

Comment: Are there any errors?  If you call generateGallery without the ajax with hard coded values does it work?

Comment: Jup, it works without any errors then! The syntax is the same!

Comment: forgot to mention: you can look at it at [link]http://www.amstein.at/iphone/index3.php#web

firefox throws some errors, but in safari it should work...

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code except that you are passing wrong data. I mean I actually don't understand why are you putting assignment operator in a string! That is why your image are not being shown. Just use the data as it is and see if it works

Comment: the only purpose was not always writing $(this).attr('id')...
i tested it also with 
<code><pre>jQT.generateGallery("portfolio-slides-"+$(this).attr('id'),data);</pre></code>
but the result was the same. 

it looks like that the function jQT.generateGallery() couldn't deal with the ajax-result or the syntax printed from php... because if i write the result as it should be by hand, everything works fine.

any other ideas?